# Play 2.5: get response body in custom http action

Tags: java, http, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.5

I'm trying to create a custom http action (https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaActionsComposition) to log request and response bodies with Play 2.5.0 Java. This is what I've got so far:

```
public class Log extends play.mvc.Action.Simple {

    public CompletionStage<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) {
        CompletionStage<Result> response = delegate.call(ctx);
        //request body is fine
        System.out.println(ctx.request().body().asText())
        //how to get response body string here while also not sabotaging http response flow of the framework?
        //my guess is it should be somehow possible to access it below?
        response.thenApply( r -> {
            //???
            return null;
        });
        return response;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logging is often considered a cross-cutting feature. In such cases the preferred way to do this in Play is to use Filters:

> The filter API is intended for cross cutting concerns that are applied indiscriminately to all routes. For example, here are some common use cases for filters:
>
> - Logging/metrics collection
> - GZIP encoding
> - Security headers

---

This works for me:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import java.util.function.Function;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import akka.stream.*;
import play.Logger;
import play.mvc.*;

public class LoggingFilter extends Filter {

    Materializer mat;

    @Inject
    public LoggingFilter(Materializer mat) {
        super(mat);
        this.mat = mat;
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> apply(
            Function<Http.RequestHeader, CompletionStage<Result>> nextFilter,
            Http.RequestHeader requestHeader) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return nextFilter.apply(requestHeader).thenApply(result -> {
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long requestTime = endTime - startTime;

            Logger.info("{} {} took {}ms and returned {}",
                requestHeader.method(), requestHeader.uri(), requestTime, result.status());
            akka.util.ByteString body = play.core.j.JavaResultExtractor.getBody(result, 10000l, mat);
            Logger.info(body.decodeString("UTF-8"));

            return result.withHeader("Request-Time", "" + requestTime);
        });
    }
}
```

What is it doing?

First this creates a new Filter which can be used along with other filters you may have. In order to get the body of the response we actually use the `nextFilter` - once we have the response we can then get the body.

As of Play 2.5 [Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/java/stream/index.html) are the weapon of choice. This means that once you use the `JavaResultExtractor`, you will get a `ByteString`, which you then have to decode in order to get the real string underneath.

---

Please keep in mind that there should be no problem in copying this logic in the `Action` that you are creating. I just chose the option with `Filter` because of the reason stated at the top of my post.

Comment: as you wrote above  

akka.util.ByteString body = play.core.j.JavaResultExtractor.getBody(result, 10000l, mat);

this will get the data from response result object same is there any way to  get request body in filter and send to controller with some changes in body?

Comment: Not really. The thing is that Filters know the request header but not the request body - as the body has not been processed at this point. The header is processed because Play is a reactive framework - no need to block and wait for the body. For manipulating the request body you have to use Action composition (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaActionsComposition). Please open a new question if you have some specific problem / want more information so that we don't hijack this topic