# Play 2.6: get response body in custom http action

Tags: java, http, playframework, playframework-2.6

A while ago, I asked [how to get the body from a Result in Play 2.5.0 Java.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986698/play-2-5-get-response-body-in-custom-http-action)

The answer was basically to use `play.core.j.JavaResultExtractor`.  I am now upgrading to 2.6, and `JavaResultExtractor` no longer exists (or at least is not public).

How does one do this in Play 2.6?

I did find `Result.body().consumeData` which seems like it might work, but also comes with the worrisome warning:

> This method should be used carefully, since if the source represents an ephemeral stream, then the entity may not be usable after this method is invoked.

I suppose that, since I am doing this in an action, I could call consumeData to get all of the data into a local variable, process that and then return a new result with the stored data.  That only fails in the case where the data is too big to fit into memory, which is not something I am currently expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In in Play 2.6 it is still possible to re-implement 2.5 functionality. Please have a look at the example that get Json body from Result:

```
public static JsonNode resultToJsonNode(final Result result, final long timeout, final Materializer mat)
    throws Exception {
    FiniteDuration finiteDuration = Duration.create(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    byte[] body = Await.result(
        FutureConverters.toScala(result.body().consumeData(mat)), finiteDuration).toArray();
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    final ObjectReader reader = om.reader();

    return reader.readTree(new ByteArrayInputStream(body));
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the result and my problem comes down to not understanding the materializer, particularly how to instantiate it. Can you illustrate?

Comment: Well, three and a half years later... You do not need to instantiate the Materializer yourself. You let it Play do by injection: `public MyAction extends Action.Simple { @Inject Materializer materializer; [...]  }`. Then, you can use the materializer in all methods in your action.